# Is there a Terminal command to get the current front most app's title?

Tags: terminal

I'm using [Übersicht](http://tracesof.net/uebersicht/) and I've created a custom menubar. I want to show the title of the current active app but my search-fu isn't great. I must be searching for it incorrectly so I figured I'd ask here.

Does such a command exist?

Comment: If you're in Terminal, then Terminal is the frontmost app...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well there is, however if you run it directly in Terminal it's just going to return Terminal, as that's the frontmost application process that's visible.

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to get name of application processes whose frontmost is true and visible is true'
```

If you want the second most, use:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to get name of second application process whose visible is true'
```

Comment: Your answer, my comment - seconds apart ;-) I do have an answer here somewhere that finds the 'second frontmost' by Applescript - I'll have to try find it...

Comment: Yeah, I was going to write it as a comment however if he's calling it in a script that's running in the background then it might have some use. :)

Comment: Yup, it works perfectly. Awesome!

Comment: We are trying to use this in some MDM automations/remediations and so the scripts are running as root. We're hitting `Execution error: Not authorized to send Apple events to System Events. (-1743)`. Is there any way to get the frontmost app without using osacript/System Events?

Answer (score 1):

To get the active application:

```
➜ osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell (first process whose frontmost is true) to return name'
```

To get the active window's title:

```
➜ osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell (first process whose frontmost is true) to return name of window 1'
```

And to get both (to avoid a race condition where the user changes windows between the two calls):

```
➜ osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell (first process whose frontmost is true) to return {name, name of window 1}'
```

Source: https://forum.keyboardmaestro.com/t/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-the-frontmost-window/2711/2